# Can I use backgroundWorker after calling hide method in VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, sqlite, backgroundworker, vb.net-2010

I have a simple question about Background worker. I have never used it so I have no Idea about how it works.
I am using VB.NET express 2010. 
All I want to do a database monitoring in a form's backgroundWorker.

Here are few things I am trying to achieve.

1. Monitoring SQLite DB file with select statement.
2. Extracting Data from DB and put them into variables.
3. Compare values with certain conditions and if something matches, pass values to another form and call it.
4. Keep on monitoring.
5. I want background worker to do this when form's `form.hide()` method is called.

Please give your valuable response and if i't not the correct way, please suggest another one so.

Comment: Could post a like the hide event you are referring to?

Comment: It is something like: Form1, inside Form1 I've backgorundWorker. if User press cancel button, it hides the Form1. If user Press any Add, Edit button on other form let's say Form2, It creates new instance of Form1 and close old one.backgorundWorker is called OnLoad

Comment: Define what you want in the question. First it was hide and now Cancel OnLoad.

Comment: I'm sorry for confusion. I have a cancel button for Form1, on which I call Form1.hide() method. All I want is to use background Worker to work when Form1.Hide() is called.

Comment: Yes, the backgroundworker will execute if the form is hide

Comment: If you are creating a new instance of Form1 everytime the user clicks a button then you will create a new background thread everytime which is a memory leak. You are better off creating an instance of Form1 as a variable on Form2 and using the constructor of Form1 to launch the background thread a single time. Then you can use the show and hide functions as needed but it will be much more manageable because you will always be refering to the single instance of Form1.

Comment: I am closing the instance properly before calling other. But I guess your method is convincing. can you give a code spinet to with background worker. As I'm new in VB.NET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hiding the form will not stop the background worker - in fact closing the form will not stop it - the form will wait for the background worker isBusy property to report false before continuing.

---

**Update in Response to new comment**

You'd probably be best using a timer and offloading the other work to a new thread, see example below. If the operation hasn't completed then the `If _worker is nothing` will stop the operation from being restarted. Be sure to set `_worker = nothing` at the end of your process for this to work though.

Also I've just typed this up quickly, it may not work out of the box but should give you a starting point.

```
Imports System.Threading

Public Class Form1

    Dim _worker As Thread

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Timer1.Interval = 10000
        'interval in milliseconds so 1000ms = 1 second / above 10000 = 10 seconds

        Timer1.Enabled = True
        Timer1.Start()

    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        StartWorkerThread()
    End Sub

    Private Sub StartWorkerThread()

        If _worker Is Nothing Then
            _worker = New Thread(AddressOf myWorker)
            _worker.Start()


        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub myWorker()
        'do your work here...use an event or a delate to fire another sub/function on the main thread if required

            'when finished
            _worker = nothing
            'Important! This will allow the operation to be started again on the timer tick
        End Sub

    End Class
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am closing  form sometime when need to call the same form for other operation. Can you help me to tell, If i close form1 how can I close background worker as well and when I call the same form, how to start background worker again?and use of isbusy property

Comment: If I understand you correctly you would need to enable the 'WorkerSupportsCancellation' Property and call .CancelAsync() on the worker before closing the form.

To have the worker start when the form loads just call .RunWorkerAsync() in the Form Load method.

Comment: The isBusy property is a read only flag, when the worker is started the property will be set to true, when stopped it will be false.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, this application was on hold for a while. Here is a deal. from form1 i want to continuously Monitor (Select statement), and meanwhile this form will be hide. for1.show() will only be called if we need to see GUI and need to perform insert/update. there is form2 as well which use to delete operation. I thought background worker might be the best option to do it so. but it's seems like it's not doing it. can i use Timer instead?

Comment: Yeah, background worker may not be the best solution, please see example code in my updated answer, hope this helps.